# Understand Configuration Pre-processor in the CruiseControl.net

Tags: xml, xsd, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

After reading document [Configuration Pre-processor](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor).

I just got some basic knowledge about it. and make summary here, hope someone could help to review it. and correct me if there is something wrong.

1. All the available `Pre-processors` are defined in the [CCNetConfigBuilder.xsd](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/CCNetConfigBuilder.xsd).

   In this xsd . It just has `define` and `scope` 2 `Pre-processors`. (Did I missed something ?)
2. From the [ccnet.xsd](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/ccnet.xsd). We can see the `CCNetConfigBuilder.xsd` is imported and the element `cruisecontrol` is the root element of configuration. like below. But I didn't know why the directive `import` doesn't need the attribute `schemaLocation` to specify the location of the imported xsd file.

   `<xs:import namespace="urn:ccnet.config.builder" />
   <xs:element name="cruisecontrol">`
3. All the child elements of `cruisecontrol` is a choice not sequence. like below:

   `<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">`

   and `define` and `scope` can occur under the `cruisecontrol` without specified order with other elements. but can't occur under the element like `project`. Right?
4. I saw [Document of Configuration_Preprocessor](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor) mention others elements like `cb:include`, `cb:ifdef`,`cb:else`, `cb:ifndef` etc. But Why I can't find its definition in the `CCNetConfigBuilder.xsd`? Please tell me if I am missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the XSD documents have been well maintained as CruiseControl.NET has not been maintained for some time. The newer features of the configuration builder are not included in the XSD